# Curl request error - 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I am using CURL for requesting data in post from url but sometime I am getting error like "416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable".

I have tried to add following code into htaccess:

```
Header set Accept-Ranges none
RequestHeader unset Range
```

But it is not working.I'm getting same error again.

What is solution of it? Please help.

Comment: You should at the very least show us the URL you are trying to access.  Better yet, include your PHP code.

Comment: Try using `Header unset Accept-Ranges` and ditch the others.

Comment: @l'L'l :it is not working